# Windows could not start service, Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: java, windows, service, installation, exe

I have created a Java program then I need to install it as windows service. 
First I run the jar directly from console and it ran as I wish, then I compile the jar to exe and I ran it as Admin ran OK.
But when I run it from windows service I got following error,

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I also tried to set Account and password on Log On Tab, but not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to resolve the actual problem with the information given by you, so I will provide you the steps necessary to debug the problem.

1. Use logging in your application to see what causes the error: [Apache Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)
2. You can use the Windows Event Viewer to see what happens when you start your Windows Service. This is very useful if the problem happens before the start of the application itself.

   Click on `Start` / `Windows symbol`, type `Event Viewer` and press `Enter`. In the left hand tree-menu, click `Windows Logs` and then `Application`.